# What would cause the fan setting on my thermostat not to turn on the air handler fan

Tags: hvac, thermostat

Just recently the fan setting on my Honeywell RTH8500D doesn't turn on the air handler.   This is a recent problem.   I usually run the air handler 24/7 during "pollen season" to filter the air in the house and had no problem simply setting the tstat fan setting to "on". The air handler is a Saving Products model HV-140H.

The only recent development is that it's been really hot here in western Washington and the A/C has been running nearly continuously.  But when it does reach setpoint and the outdoor unit shuts off, the air handler shuts off too, even though the fan is set to "on" on the t-stat.  The air handler runs normally when there is a call for cooling.

There is another air handler (2nd floor) with it's own t-stat and the fan setting operates normally, like the other one used to do.

Any ideas why the fan setting is suddenly inoperative on the 1st floor tstat?

[image: AH with cover removed][image: Iced over evap coil.]

Comment: Since it used to work and works with a call for cooling the battery would be my first guess as on some stats the “fan on” is a separate relay and a low battery can cause this.

Comment: @EdBeal thanks for the idea.   I pulled the tstat off it's housing and turns out there were never any batteries in it since it's install about 15 years ago. I went ahead and installed 3 AAA cells anyway and it made no difference. So obviously the tstat was powered by the AH. I do hear a lite click on the tstat when I set fan to "on", so I think it's working correctly.   I'm more concerned with the AH, there was tons of condensation seeping out of the seams in the ductwork. And no, the condensate drain isn't blocked, I checked.  Just hope it didn't hit the electronics.

Comment: **there was tons of condensation seeping out of the seams in the ductwork** is your drain pan overflowing ? Is the heat exchange coil frozen ?

Comment: @Ruskes  the AH has these slanted metal mesh curtains (for lack of a better word) that supposedly are to catch the condensate from the evaporator coils, but they are not very effective.   I'm going to pull the covers now and see what I find.

Comment: Metal mesh is washable, so service them, wash and de-grease.

Comment: With the high heat and humidity we are having you are probably producing more water than normal I know my small mini split the housing was sweating and that has never happened before, yours may be producing moisture on the outside of the AH, normally if the fan will run in cooling the G (I think) terminal will pull the fan in also. Definitely check for water on the board.

Comment: The sequence of events. 1- high pollen contaminates the filer. 2- filter does not let enough air true to the coil. 3- the coil freezes over. 4- once the coil tows it generates high volume of water. All this has nothing to do with the Fan not running in stand alone mode, but running in the Cool mode. 5- Wash the metal mesh inserts.

Comment: @Ruskes  Thanks for the comment. I changed the filter less than a month ago (4" pleated filter) and inspected it today, it's not clogged at all, but that was a good suggestion.  Next those mesh inserts are not accessible w/o major disassembly of the AH. :(   Lastly, the tray where the fan is doesn't seem to have any sort of drainage.  You can easily see the water bubbling up where the fan is attached.  Bad install? Maybe they were counting on the mesh curtains to intercept all the condensate.   Also, condensate dripping all over the electronics. YIKES.,

Comment: the drip pan must have drain !!! to clean those curtains and the heat exchange coil, go get a spray made for that purpose, and just spray it on. And you do have large ice build up, which is not good. Maybe from Fan not running in stand alone mode. Use multimeter on thermostat and check if Fan gets 24 Volt when in Fan only mode.

Comment: @Ruskes  I agree, I think it was a bad install or at least badly designed. There is a condensate drain which goes to the wire mesh collection tray (higher than the drip pan), but it doesn't work well, so condensate ends up in the drip pan with no place to go.  I'll have to figure out a way to drain that pan someplace, but more troublesome is the water dripping over the electronics.

Comment: In an above living space installation (Like an attic), there should be two drain/drip pans.  The first is built into the air handler, and should discharge through a (usually) PVC pipe with a P-trap outside the house, or maybe into a drain (if allowed).  The second pan is installed under the air handler and it too has a PVC drain that runs outside to a place where water coming out of it would be visible (this is key).  The secondary pan should only have water in it if the internal drain pan is clogged.  That's the reason for making sure the exit from the second pan is clearly visible.

Comment: does the fan's motor case get warm when it's doing nothing instead of running in background mode?

Answer (score 1):

The 8500D is a pretty straightforward thermostat - not a lot to go wrong there.  I would start looking at your wiring terminations for loose or broken connections.

The thermostat is one of those types that has a wallplate that accepts the wire connections and the thermostat itself slots into pins on the wallplate.  This can lead to broken connections when pulling the thermo off the wall to change batteries, etc.

Also check the air handler end, specifically the 'G' terminal.  If that became disconnected, the fan would still run automatically when a call for heat or cooling is received, but not when the call goes back to fan only.

Comment: Thanks Chris:  I"ll pull the cover off the AH and inspect.  The tstat has never been pulled out of its wallplate since it was installed 15 years ago (see my comment / resp to Ed Beal, above).

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate problems.

**Ice on the heat exchange coil**

Clearly that should not be.

Possible causes, Fan is not working, or AC is cooling too much.

**Fan only mode not working on one thermostat**

Model Honeywell RTH8500D

According to they manual you must have working batteries installed for proper operation.

Since Fan is working in Cool mode, it is not the Fan

Fan only is also working from second thermostat.

Clearly something wrong with one thermostat.

Carefully compare wiring and make sure the batteries are new and installed properly.

Make sure the settings on the thermostat are in accordance to the manual [manual](https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/69-0000s/69-1725.pdf)

Comment: Wouldn't a low refrigerant charge also cause icing of the indoor coils & possibly the refrigerant lines?

Comment: Yes it would cause that

Comment: actually the fan could run in cool but not constant mode if it or a capacitor or whatever was failing; they often run at 25% power when "on on" and 75-100% power when "auto on". WD40 might reduce the friction enough to get that 25% working again.

Comment: @dandavis are you talking about adjustable speed fan ?

Comment: adjustable if you're comfortable swapping jumpers on the control board. the defaults i've seen give non-call-mode fan a lower speed, which might not be enough all-the-sudden. other fan problems would probably stop it from ever spinning...

Comment: @dandavis I like that, swap the jumpers, any idea how to do that.

Comment: it's different on each model. there's some mentioning of fan speed in the diagrams at the end of https://www.hi-velocity.com/en/hv/Series-HV-Installation-Manual-010118.pdf. It looks like the fan motoro capacitor is rusting or corroeded, so it very well might be the "real" issue here, even if sending it more juice gets it spinning again in background...

Comment: @dandavis Thank you, I do not have that system, mine is simple single speed Fan